# How to target a particular tmux session

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a script that uses Tmux to run commands on a remote system and sometimes it screws up due to the way Tmux's `list-windows` command is run. For example, if I have two Tmux sessions on the remote server: `session1` and `session2`. Depending on whether or not I am active in session 1 or session 2, running `tmux list-windows` from *outside* of Tmux gives me two completely different results:

Here's an example:

```
[root:kali:]# tmux ls
session1: 2 windows (created Tue Nov  5 18:22:58 2019)
session2: 3 windows (created Wed Nov  6 18:21:04 2019)

[root:kali:]# tmux list-windows
0: zsh* (1 panes) [215x53] [layout 5de0,215x53,0,0,30] @28 (active)
1: tool (1 panes) [80x24] [layout 5963,80x24,0,0,33] @31
2: script- (1 panes) [215x53] [layout 5de4,215x53,0,0,34] @32

[root:kali:]# tmux a -t session1
[detached (from session session1)]

[root:kali:]# tmux list-windows
0: zsh- (1 panes) [215x53] [layout bb5d,215x53,0,0,0] @0
1: msf* (1 panes) [215x53] [layout dde6,215x53,0,0,27] @25 (active)
```

In the example above, all I did was simply attach to session 1 and then detach from it. Next, when running `tmux list-windows`, you can clearly see that it shows the windows that are from session1 instead of session2.

Is there a way with Tmux to simply list the windows from a particular session from *outside* of Tmux? This would literally solve all of my issues that I've been facing with this for quite some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a particular session for most tmux commands.

```sh
tmux list-windows -t session2
```

`-t` is how you choose to attach to a certain session (`tmux a -t session1`), or even a certain session/window/pane combination.

For instance, if I have a session `sess`, that has 3 windows, each with 4 panes, and I want to run `htop` in the first window, third pane, I'd do

```sh
tmux send-keys -t sess:0.2 'htop' Enter
```

as window/panes in tmux are 0-indexed.

Comment: Thanks. Seeing a target-session name is the $session:win-id:pane-id made many things clearer.